# Eight queens in Java in recursion

Tags: java

This is my Java code for eight queens. I don't know why it place same results for eight times.
In this code, diagonal is not included.

```
import java.util.*;

class eightTeight {
    Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public void print() {
        if (s.size() < 8) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                if (!s.contains(i)) {
                    s.add(i);
                    print();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
        return;
    }
}
```

It seems that once return runs, the s still keeps the data. Appreciated to any help.

Comment: ahh this is definitely homework. it was my homework 5 years ago:)

Comment: Yes. We must have studied with the same teacher :-). Anyway the question is well asked.

Comment: I've done these algorithms like 5 years ago too =O.

Answer (score 0):

"I don't know why it place same results for eight times".

Because you are calling the method recursively 8 times, and for each time it prints the result.

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            if(!s.contains(i)){
                s.add(i);
                print();
            }
        }
```

Take the print to outside the method.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, when you pass the object to the method, you copy the reference to the object. So, changes made to the object are visible by all references to that object (including the one you keep in the calling method).

There are two solutions for it:

1. Copy the `HashSet` before doing modifications, and do the modifications to the copy. In case a solution is found, return the new copy. In case it does not work, return the original copy.
2. Use a data structure thtat depends in an index, so you can ignore all values that should not still be set. For example an array, if you are iterating for the 5th queen you can ignore the values of the fifth, sixth, seventh and eighth queens if they are set.

I find more clear the queens problem implemented with an int array, but that is left to everybodys taste.

Answer (score 0):

It caused by your recursively invoking

```
print();
```

And you should realize that ***there is no global variable*** in JAVA. Every time you invoke "print()" will just use the empty "Set", then you add sth into it, and print it out. There are eight times recursion here, therefore there are eight times that console print out the same thing. This is why your fail the expectation.